# How to generate registration no. in PHP?

Tags: php

I want generate registration no of user but registration no should be:

First two digit no. should be year as - 15

Second two digit no. should be month as - 06

Third two should be Character which already assign as - SY

Fourth should be No as - 012

So my registration no will make as - 1506SY012. How to generate it in PHP code?

Comment: Have you tried or researched anything yourself? SO isn't a "write this code for me" (no matter how trivial) but rather a "please help me with this programming issue/problem" site.

Comment: You could be more specific, try something on your own, show the code you tried... I guess this is really easy but yeah... We need somethings from your side, some effort

Answer (score 2):

Seeing this question is still open, I will post the following as a solution and there are a few ways you can go about this.

- Explode the date and separate them as an array and assigning a variable to each array.
- Use date directly
- Concatenate the variables.

Using the `date()` function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

- `y` = A two digit representation of a year. Examples: 99 or 03
- `m` = Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros. 01 through 12

Explode on the date:

```
$date1 = date("y-m-d");
$dateArray=explode('-',$date1);

$array1 = $dateArray[0];
echo $array1;

$array2 = $dateArray[1];
echo $array2;

// Should you want to use the third array
// $array3 = $dateArray[2];
// echo $array3;
```

Sidenote for the above: You can concatenate (link together) the variables into one, rather than echoing them seperately. I will let you do that.

Using the date directly and concatenating:

```
$date = date("ym");
$final = $date . "SY" . "012";
echo $final;
```

or

```
$date = date("ym");
$letters = "SY";
$numbers = "012";

$result = "$date$letters$numbers";
echo $result;
```

---

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
- http://php.net/explode

Comment: how to change the last number that should be increment.. as 1506SY12 second no. as 1506SY13 third automatic change when user click submit button?

Comment: @PawanSrivastava That wasn't what you wrote in your original post. I answered that question. You need to post a new question now and accept this one.